# Add attribute to each child node in custom foreach binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am building a custom binding "sortable".
1) the sortable binding extends the foreach binding.
2) add attribute "draggable="true" to each child node.

```
<div data-bind="sortable:{foreach: myCollection}">
  <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
</div>
```

here is the code i want to generate.

```
<div data-bind="sortable:{foreach: myCollection}">
  <div draggable="true" data-bind="text: $data">item1</div>
  <div draggable="true" data-bind="text: $data">item2</div>
  <div draggable="true" data-bind="text: $data">item3</div>
</div>
```

Using the following custom binding I managed to render the items, but I cannot figure out how to add an attribute to each child node.

```
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
  var value = valueAccessor().foreach;
  ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { foreach: {data: value} });

  // add attribute draggable="true" to each child node
  // TODO

  // tell ko that we have already handled binding the children of this element
  return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
}
```

I tried to use applyBindingsToDescendants but to no avail.

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/jihupawero/edit?html,js,output

ps: I dont want to add the attribute in the binding html (template) because I think this should be hidden from the user and done inside the sortable-binding.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds a bit silly .. but sometime simple things get overlooked :) so if there is no logic to determine true or false (if it is true always) couldn't you just say  <div draggable="true"  data-bind="text: $data"></div> in your binding HTML?

Comment: This would work but adding the draggable attribute should be done inside the sortable binding. I also need to add an eventhandler and the user of the binding shouldnt need to worry about the interna by copy&pasting attributes and eventhandlers. The user should only need to use the sortable binding without copy&pasting stuff he doesnt need to think about.

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your task ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/domapajalo/1/edit?html,js,output))?

```
<div data-bind="sortable: myCollection">
    <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
</div>


ko.bindingHandlers.sortable = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { foreach: value });
        $(element).children().attr("draggable", true);
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

#### Update 1

```
<div draggable="true" data-bind="text: $data"></div>
```

or

```
<div data-bind="text: value, attr: { draggable: isDraggable }"></div>
```

where your model should contain "value" and "isDraggable" attributes:

```
var viewModel = function(){
  var model = {};
  model.myCollection = ko.observableArray([{ value:1, isDraggable: true}, { value:2, isDraggable: false},{ value:3, isDraggable: true}]);
  return model;
}();
```

Comment: It does work. But is there also a way to do this with knockout?

Comment: @davewood - check update 1 (i haven't tested it but almost sure it works)

Comment: @davewood I am thinking you want to make it more knockout for the person using this custom binding ... in that case a suggestion would be to make the draggable a configurable thing, so if I am using this binding I would expect to write <div data-bind="sortable: {foreach:myCollection,draggable:true}"> ... (would be an easy modification to this answer) and I think it is perfectly fine to do DOM manipulation in the custom binding ... that is the whole point :)

Comment: Thank you for the valuable input, but I dont wont the user to think about (and declare) whether or not isDraggable should be true or not. The binding declaration should be a simple as possible. Ideally just 'sortable: myCollection'.

Also, a per-item declaration of the draggable attribute is redundant for my usecase.

Maybe my real question is: How can I apply a binding to all direct child-nodes of a foreach binding.  Just like applyBindingsToNode does to the "current" binding-node.

Comment: @Sam.C suggested you to use '<div data-bind="sortable: {foreach:myCollection,draggable:true}">' syntax. Does it meet your requirements? What's your actual scenario?